# Preview image before upload in php

Tags: php

I am uploading image using php.

However, i want to see image preview of selected image before upload.

This is My form:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fupForm" method="post">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" />
  <img class="basic-img" src="#"/>
</form>
```

I check the similar question [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) But solution is not working for me

Comment: And what exactly does not work? Please describe it in details, and provide any screenshots if necessary.

Comment: Have you got the JavaScript?

Comment: This is my js code function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.basic-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#file").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code which you mention in comment seems ok , if this is not working you can try it by calling function in onload

```
$(function() {
    $(":file").change(function() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('.basic-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

Comment: It is working but can you please tell me what is the problem in my code